# Xamarin: Exception when finding button with Marked on System Alert Window

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I am testing pressing OK on SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW on Android using Xamarin testcloud.

However, I get below error. Has anyone tried testing on alert window? Does Xamarin test cloud work on normal android activities or alert windows as well?

```
Exception: System.Exception: Unable to find element. Query for Button("btnOK") gave no results.
```

I am using the usual query, and button is defined properly.

```
Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> MyButton = c => c.Button("btnOK");

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
.. 
</>
```

PS: I can see that alert window is shows up correctly in screenshot when test was marked failed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Marked` instead of `Button` method because it matches common values like the `id` on Android, see also [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Marked/p/System.String/).

Thus, this should work:

```
Func< AppQuery, AppQuery> MyButton = c => c.Marked("btnOK");
```

Comment: Why should the original poster try this? Please explain you solution.

Comment: Not sure why "< AppQuery, AppQuery >" was not visible at first, if thats what ur concern was. but using "Marked" instead of c.Button was main thing.. Let me know if you still needs explanation

Comment: At first, please format code as code in the edit view, see help there. Then explain, why you replaced `Button` by `Marked`.

Comment: Because marked has always worked for me  on both platform :-http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Marked/p/System.String/

Comment: I have made an edit to your answer, to show you what should be at least included in an answer. Accept it if you like it. I see now, that it must read `method` instead of `message`, please fix it afterwards. I can't do this until my edit is accepted.

Comment: Also, according to this :- http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Button/p/System.String/   for "Button" to work - "For Android: An element that has class (or inherits from) android.widget.Button" but ImageButton does not inherit from android.widget.Button.. Hope it helps.

Comment: If this is a relevant detail, then include it in your answer instead of just posting it as a comment. Also change the word "message" to "method" in the answer.